# Entity Framework - link to all items in a table, then add a new one?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 2 simple `C#` objects (user and department) as follows (using EF code first):

```
public class User
{
     int UserID {get; set;}
     string Name {get; set;}
     List<Department> Departments {get; set;}
}

public class Department
{
     int DepartmentID {get; set;}
     string Name {get; set;}
     List<User> Users {get;set}
}
```

I can create a user and add multiple departments to it, all great.

What I would like to do is set the user as connected to "All Departments".

Now although I could add all departments to a user, if later on I add a new department I would have to remember to add it to that user as well - not ideal.

My initial thought (rightly or wrongly) was to add a boolean AllDepartments property to the user.  However although I can make it work, its not clean at all.  I have to remember to check that boolean whenever I call a user, and build the department list as a separate query (so its not really relational in the database either).

My ideal would be to create a brand new department, and on retrieving that department it would already have all the users that are supposed to be connected to all departments, be navigable via the List property.

Has anyone come across this before and solved this situation cleanly?

Comment: What if you create a new column in the Department entity with the id of every user? at the end you want that anyway. Or create a third Entity called AssignedDepartment with the UserID and DepartmentID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facing the same problem I use a `departmentGroup` table, each department belonging/being to at least one group.

- then a user belongs to a department group (and no more to a department).
- then I have a business rule that add every new department to a 'All departments group'

All solutions have their pro and cons. The main con (imho) of this solution is that a user belonging to the all department belongs automatically to a new top secret department. Are you sure this is what you want ?

Comment: Actually this layer of abstraction would probably work for me.  It simplifies the extra code required to just adding/removing documents.  It isn't as "pretty" from the DB side but will work well.  I'm importing an old DB which uses 0 as the departmentID for all documents, and that causes lots of issues where the code is littered across every call.